# Use Perl/Regex to parse 'structured' dump

Tags: regex, perl, perl-data-structures, regex-group

I was working with a proprietary software, and had to deal with very long/tedious analysis among the components of that software.

To try to improve my productivity in this task, I used the software generated Report and as trying to parse it, my bet was that Perl was perfectly suited to it.

The reports looks like (after removing page numbers):

```
Category one: NAME1    - Some free form text description goes here
    Used by Cat2 Resources:
        CAT2_NAME - Anoter free form text description here (there are lots of them, but they are pretty much useless, since no one cares about them, probably could not be that long.)
        CAT2_NAME2 - And so on.
        CAT2_NAME4 - U guessed it!
    Uses Resource Cat4:
        CAT4_NAMED   - A meaningless description that where copied from an unrelated resource (Save as...)


Category one: NAME7    - Description
    Used by Cat2 Resources:
        CAT2_NAME - Text
        CAT2_NAME5 - And so on.

        CAT2_NAME4 - U guessed it!
    Uses Resource Cat4:
        CAT4_NAME_  - Some names don't make any sense.

Category TWO: NAME7    - Description of another Category
    Used by Cat3 Resources:
        CAT3_NAME - Text
        CAT3_NAME5 - And so on.
        CAT3_NAME4 - U guessed it!
    Uses Resource Cat4:
        CAT4_NAME_  - Some names don't make any sense.
```

To be completely clear

- All element names where named in CAPITAL LETTERS, numbers and underscore ("_")
- Almost all elements relate with each others
- There are orphan elements
- None of the names had their categories included (I put those on my example to make them more readable)
- The spaces at the start of each line under a paragraph/sub-paragraph where one or two TABs
- There are some random empty lines here and there, I plan to clean this file a little better, but I am in a hurry right now.

I would like to be able to generate something like:

Out_CAT1_CAT2.csv

```
NAME1,CAT2_NAME
NAME1,CAT2_NAME2
NAME1,CAT2_NAME4
NAME7,CAT2_NAME
NAME7,CAT2_NAME5
NAME7,CAT2_NAME4
```

Out_CAT1_CAT4.csv

```
NAME1,CAT4_NAMED
NAME7,CAT2_NAME4
NAME7,CAT4_NAME_
```

Out_CAT2_CAT3.scv

```
NAME7,CAT3_NAME
NAME7,CAT3_NAME5
NAME7,CAT3_NAME4
```

Out_CAT2_CAT4.scv

```
NAME7,CAT4_NAME_
```

To parse this file, I tried (and failed) one first approach that consisted of grabbing a complete paragraph (That one that started as Category/again, there is no 'Category' on that label, only the category name, like database/processing model, etc)

### Approach 1

I tried to use multi line regex like `/(<?=^Category one :)[A-Z0-9_]+.*+$(^\s.*$)+/m` intending to capture a complete paragraph to an array (or yet best an array to each level one Category) but have tried a lot of combinations at https://regex101.com/ without any lucky.

My aim was to create an array of such Cat1 paragraphs, that I would in turn parse with a subroutine. But I failed (I would appreciate some advice to it in comments please).

Them I turned over to a completely different approach, I wrote something along os the lines of

### Approach 2

```
while(<>){
    if(/^Category one: /){
        $mode = CAT1PARSING;
        # Used regex to grab the name as it came in this same line after the colon.
        $cat1Name = /regex/;
    }
    elsif(/^Category TWO: /){
        $mode = CAT2PARSING;
    }
    ...

    if($mode == CAT1PARSING){
        # Used some regex to capture the name and description as elements of an array
        push @cat1Array, ($el1, $el2) = $_ =~ (/regex/);
    }
    ...
}
```

# Here I do some formatting to dump the same info to a lot of CSV files one to each category/sub-category pair, with  the appropriated headers

#### I do some formatting to dump the same info to a lot of CSV files one to each category/sub-category pair, with  the appropriated headers

My real program was made using approach 2, sets two control variables $mode and $subMode (I am luck that there are only two such levels), but I am unsatisfied with it.

I am not sure if it is what is called a 'state machine', anyone can confirm?

So of course I am not asking one question but a lot, nevertheless my main questions are:

**There are any ways in which I could implement this with regex? As stated in the approach one? How?**

Comment: What structure/output are you looking for? Do you need to maintain ordering if the 'CAT_NAME' entries?

Comment: For each `^Category` paragraph, are you looking to just find the cat name words and not the values? Also, are you looking to keep each paragraph data separate from other paragraphs? The regex is simple, it just depends on what you're trying to do. Also, it's better to slurp all the data into a single string before you parse it.

Comment: `None of the names had their categories included (I put those on my example to make them more readable)` In this case, it would be better to show raw text, without your annotations.

Comment: @Sobrique I am generating a CSV dump as noted in a comment at the very last line in the code block under **Approach 2**

Comment: @sln I can't disclose my real category names (NDA) but lets say they were Orange, Apples and Blueberry. Anything that could parse such fruit names categories would be easier to translate to the desired grammar. (and easier to generalize to other applications also).

Comment: You have just shown us your log file and said that you want to parse it. It would help a lot if you explained what result you wanted

Comment: @sln: *"Also, it's better to slurp all the data into a single string before you parse it"* That's very misleading. It's probably not "better" at all, and may not even be possible.

Comment: @Borodin I am generating a CSV dump as noted in a comment at the very last line in the code block under **Approach 2**

Comment: One question: the text after the names, like `CAT2_NAME` are always in one line (single-line)? or they could be multiline?

Comment: @Rafareino  I added a solution to my answer, interpreting your comments that "_Category_" stands for a word out of a fixed list, for example as  you say "_Orange, Apples and Blueberry_".

Comment: @Borodin  - I guess I meant virtual ram. On the other hand no paged memory and  2k ram available after bootup would be a problem if a record $/ falls on a  5k boundary.

Comment: @sln: Not at all; the operating system does the paging, but you should do all you can to limit the working set of your program so that it doesn't have to be paged out. And I'm not "playing" to anyone, I'm simply trying to get a response from you regarding your fallacious claim that slurping a file before parsing it is somehow "better" while you appear to be avoiding having to substantiate it by changing the subject to the irrelevant topic of virtual memory. Accordingly I take it that you're aware that your assertion has no basis in fact, and you are simply shy of having to admit it.

Comment: @sln: The moderators deleted those comments because I asked them to. The thread was way off topic, and I don't believe you would ever admit to being mistaken. If you have never heard of the *working set* of a process then you should look it up. It is at the heart of the concept of paged memory, and you can become better informed without publicly confessing your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Rule one in 'parsing ad-hoc formats' is: Find the field separator.

In this case - You've got "Category" at start of line. If you had a proper 'blank line' then you could use paragraph mode, but you don't, so:

```
local $/ = "\nCategory";
```

To match it, with no whitepace.

Rule two - look for the structure in your records. It looks like you have 'Uses' and 'Used' segments, and within those - key-value pairs, indented with `-` separators. Do you need to maintain ordering of those? Because if not, then a hash would make sense, and if so, then you need an array.

And then third question - what does the output need to look like? You mention CSV, but ... if your data is hierarchical (like it is) then something like JSON might do it better.

Anyway, parsing would look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my @records;

local $/ = "\nCategory";
while (<>) {

   print "Record $. looks like: \n\n";
   print;
   print "\n\n----\n\n";


   my ( $used_cat, $used_text, $uses_cat, $uses_text ) =
     m/^\s{4}Used by (\w+) Resources:(.*)Uses Resource (\w+):(.*)/gms;


   print "::\n";
   print $used_text;
   print "\n:::\n";

   my $this_record;
   $this_record->{used_cat} = $used_cat;
   $this_record->{uses_cat} = $uses_cat;

   for ( split /\n/, $used_text ) {

      if ( my ( $key, $value ) = m/^\s+(\w+)\s*-\s*(.*)$/ ) {
         print "$key => $value\n";
         $this_record->{used}{$key} = $value;
      }
   }

   for ( split /\n/, $uses_text ) {

      if ( my ( $key, $value ) = m/^\s+(\w+)\s*-\s*(.*)$/ ) {
         print "$key => $value\n";
         $this_record->{uses}{$key} = $value;
      }
   }

   push @records, $this_record;
}

print Dumper \@records;
print "JSON Output:\n";
print to_json ( \@records, { pretty => 1 } );
```